# Chrome on Ubuntu desktop over RDP causes keyboard to become disabled

Tags: google-chrome, xrdp

This one is interesting.

I have Ubuntu 19.04 installed on Hyper-V, and accessible via RDP.  This works, except that when I start Chrome, the keyboard is disabled - no applications can receive keystrokes.except for password dialogs which can still read the keyboard.

As soon as I close Chrome, the keyboard becomes active again.

Weird, huh?  Any ideas?

Comment: If I turn off syncing with my Google account, the problem goes away.

Comment: I tried Chromium - and I get exactly the same problem - so I thought it might be an extension.

Comment: I disabled all extensions - and the problem remained.  I went back to the default theme - still there.  Disabled sync - and problem gone.

Comment: Any ideas?  This is really odd.  No issues whatsoever with Chrome on Windows.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that when the keyboard does not work, it does not work for ANY application, not just Chrome.

Comment: And it is also limited to when I use RDP - it does not happen when I use the Hyper-V console.

Comment: In my case, most other applications, such as the Text Editor or Terminal are still getting keyboard inputs. Chrome doesn't work. Visual Studio Code also doesn't. presumably because its Electron GUI engine is based on the same Chromium browser engine. Turning off the sync worked for Chrome but not Visual Studio Code.